# Copy from a valid csv file but postgres blind to find

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to copy csv data to a table with

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dbuser postgres  :dbpassword 1618 :database analysis
COPY us_counties_2010
FROM 'data/us_counties_2010.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
#+end_src
```

It report error

```
psql:/tmp/babel-x3dXSm/sql-in-zo3MDm:3: ERROR:  could not open file "data/us_counties_2010.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

The error `"data/us_counties_2010.csv" for reading: No such file or directory` does not exits, make no sense.

Because, it does exsit

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
ls -l 'data/us_counties_2010.csv' | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: -rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 1170359 Dec  7 10:22 data/us_counties_2010.csv
```

What's the problem? Does postgres developers invented yet another arcane path rules to prohibit users?

Comment: Are the file and the server on the same machine?

Comment: yes, they are all of local. @klin

Comment: The o.s. user (usually `postgres`) who is the owner of Postgres server has to have read access to the file.

Comment: but the file is readable to all ` -rw-rw-r--` @klin

Comment: Oh yes, use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the file exist?  You are using an relative path.

When you use "COPY", [what you get is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html):

> The path will be interpreted relative to the working directory of the server process (normally the cluster's data directory), not the client's working directory.

Using `\copy` rather than `COPY` will get you not only the client's permissions, but also the clients working directory when searching for the file.

Answer (score 0):

File permissions? I see that "me" has permissions. What user is postgresql?

Comment: postgres is the default superuser.